# How to change color of the chapter number, with this style?

Tags: color, numbering, chapters, titlesec, book-design

I need to change the color of the **chapter number**, but not its title.  The answers I've found elsewhere weren't very helpfull yet.  Here's a MWE to show the style I'm using:

```
\documentclass[11pt,letterpaper,twoside]{book}
\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}
\usepackage[nomath]{lmodern}
\usepackage[total={6in,10in},left=1.5in,top=0.5in,includehead,includefoot]{geometry}
\usepackage{microtype}
\usepackage[bottom]{footmisc}  % Options : [perpage], [symbol], [multiple]
\usepackage{mathtools}
\usepackage[dvipsnames,table]{xcolor}
\usepackage[pagestyles,medium]{titlesec}

% Main header :
\newpagestyle{principal}{
    \sethead[\thepage][][\itshape\small\MakeUppercase{\chaptername\ \thechapter. \chaptertitle}]{\itshape\small\MakeUppercase{\thesection\ \sectiontitle}}{}{\thepage}
    \headrule
}

\begin{document}

\mainmatter

\pagestyle{principal}

\chapter{Chapter title}

Some funny line

\newpage

Blabla bla.

\end{document}
```

Preview, with the part that I want to change shown in red:

[image]

I don't want to change the font style, size and position.  Just the color of "Chapter #".  How can I do that, using the **titlesec** package?  Its documentation isn't clear here.  I don't want to change the header.